# Laravel edit shallow nested resource

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-request, laravel-resource

I'm using the following resource using [shallow nesting](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#shallow-nesting)

```
Route::resource('organizations.emaildomains', 'OrganizationEmailDomainController', ['except' => ['show']])->shallow();
```

Got the following table with two records which is the result of an index.blade.php

[image]

Let's say we want to edit `tiagoperes.eu` to `stackoverflow.com`. I'd go to the edit view

[image]

change the respective field and click the save button. This is the result

[image]

As you can see, **the record isn't updated**.

Checking the `$request->all()` in the update() of the controller

[image]

and the form data in the network tab

[image]

and the data is posted to

```
http://localhost/app/public/emaildomains/7
```

which matches the URI in shallow nesting.

---

In edit.blade.php I have the following form to handle the updates

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('emaildomains.update', ['emaildomain' => $email_domain->id]) }}" autocomplete="off">
    @csrf
    @method('put')

    <h6 class="heading-small text-muted mb-4">{{ __('Email Domain information') }}</h6>
    <div class="pl-lg-4">
        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('organization_id') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-organization_id">{{ __('Organization') }}</label>
            <select name="organization_id" id="input-organization" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('organization_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Organization') }}" required>
                @foreach ($organizations as $organization)
                    <option value="{{ $organization->id }}" {{ $organization->id == old('organization_id', $email_domain->organization->id) ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $organization->name }}</option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
            @include('alerts.feedback', ['field' => 'organization_id'])
        </div>

        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email_domain') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email_domain">{{ __('Email Domain') }}</label>
            <input type="text" name="email_domain" id="input-email_domain" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('email_domain') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Email Domain') }}" value="{{ old('email_domain', $email_domain->email_domain) }}" required autofocus>

            @include('alerts.feedback', ['field' => 'email_domain'])
        </div>

        <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

and here's both the edit and update methods in the `OrganizationEmailDomainController`

```
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\OrganizationEmailDomain  $email_domain
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Request $request, OrganizationEmailDomain $email_domain, Organization $model)
{
    $path = $request->path();

    $id = (int)explode('/', $path)[1];

    $emailDomain = OrganizationEmailDomain::find($id);

    return view('organizations.emaildomains.edit', ['email_domain' => $emailDomain->load('organization'), 'organizations' => $model::where('id', $emailDomain->organization_id)->get(['id', 'name'])]);        

}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\OrganizationEmailDomain  $email_domain
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, OrganizationEmailDomain $email_domain)
{

    $email_domain->update($request->all());

    $organization_id = (int)$request->all()['organization_id'];

    return redirect()->route('organizations.emaildomains.index', ['organization' => $organization_id])->withStatus(__("Org's email domain successfully updated."));
}
```

and this is the model (notice I'm using a table with a different name than the expected by default - `protected $table = 'email_domains';`)

```
class OrganizationEmailDomain extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'email_domain', 'organization_id'
    ];

    protected $table = 'email_domains';

    /**
     * Get the organization
     *
     * @return \Organization
     */
    public function organization()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Organization::class);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When injecting a model ID to a route or controller action, you will often query the database to retrieve the model that corresponds to that ID. Laravel route model binding provides a convenient way to automatically inject the model instances directly into your routes. For example, instead of injecting a OrganizationEmailDomain's ID, you can inject the entire OrganizationEmailDomain model instance that matches the given ID.

Laravel automatically resolves Eloquent models defined in routes or controller actions whose type-hinted variable names match a route segment name. For example:

```
use App\OrganizationEmailDomain;

Route::put('emaildomains/{emailDomain}', [OrganizationEmailDomainController::class, 'update']);
```

Then the following should be in your controller

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \App\OrganizationEmailDomain  $emailDomain
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, OrganizationEmailDomain $emailDomain)
{

    $emailDomain->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('organizations.emaildomains.index', [
            'organization' => $request->organization_id
    ])->withStatus(__("Org's email domain successfully updated."));
}
```

Note that if the variable name `$emailDomain` is different from the route segment `{emailDomain}`, then laravel will not be able to resolve the model. Therefore you will get an empty OrganizationEmailDomain model and it will not update any data. So make sure to put the same name defined in the route.

To check which is the correct name of the route run the command `php artisan route:list` and you will see the route and the name of the segment.

---

### Edit

In order to solve the problem, I ran

```
php artisan route:list
```

which showed

> organizations/{organization}/emaildomains/{emaildomain}                   | organizations.emaildomains.update

So, changing the `OrganizationEmailDomainController.php` to

```
/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\OrganizationEmailDomainRequest  $request
 * @param  \App\OrganizationEmailDomain  $emaildomain
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(OrganizationEmailDomainRequest $request, OrganizationEmailDomain $emaildomain)
{

    $emaildomain->update($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('organizations.emaildomains.index', ['organization' => $request->organization_id])->withStatus(__("Org's email domain successfully updated."));
}
```

was enough.

[image]

Notice that the only needed change was in the controller from `$email_domain` to `$emaildomain` yet also removed the unnecessary bit to get the organization_id and used instead the suggsted above through the $request.

Comment: Thank you MrEduar. Will give the bounty whenever possible.