# Laravel 8: Argument 2 passed must be an instance of

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 8 to develop an Online Forum. And I made this form for updating an answer of a user:

```
<form action="{{ route('update.answer', [$anss->id, $que->id]) }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <textarea name="answer" id="answer" class="form-control" rows="7">{{ $ans->answer }}</textarea>
    @error('answer')
        <div class="text-red-500 mt-2 text-sm">
            {{ $message }}
        </div>
    @enderror
    <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500 BJadidBold">ثبت تفییرات</button>
</form>
```

And here is the route for this:

```
Route::post('questions/{ans}/{que}' , [QuestionController::class, 'updateAnswer'])->name('update.answer');
```

And this is also the Method of `QuestionController`:

```
public function updateAnswer(Answer $anss, Question $que)
    {
        $validate_data = Validator::make(request()->all(),[
           'answer' => 'required'
        ])->validated();

        $answer = Answer::findOrFail($anss);
        $answer->update($validate_data);
        return view('questions.question',[
            'show' => $que,
        ]);
    }
```

But now the problem is, whenever I submit the form in order to update answer, I get this as error:

**Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\QuestionController::updateAnswer() must be an instance of App\Models\Question, string given, called in F:\xampp\htdocs\gooyanet\root\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Controller.php on line 54**

I don't why I get this error, because as you can see I have passed `$que->id` at Action to `Question $que` as the 2nd parameter of `udpateAnswer()` method.

So what is your idea about this? How can I solve this issue?

I would really appreciate if you share your idea or suggestion with me.

Thanks...

Comment: Everything looks good as you describe, try the nonsensical options "php artisan route: clear" .. because it looks like something is cached

Comment: I think the variable name should matches the {ans} URI segment. Try changing  the variable name to $ans or the uri parameter to {anss}

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ is right, the problem is the typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because your variable in the controller is called `$anss` and in your route is called `ans`

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66495887/13522473) I have given in another topic.